# Can I test In App Billing without publishing the app to Alpha or Beta?

Tags: android

This question is not a duplicate as Google has done some modifications as far as I am reading.

I would like to test my app having in app billing without publishing the app to alpha or beta. Is that still possible?

I've tried it while it's still in draft, I installed the same APK that I uploaded on my test device, and clicked the buy button to initiate a purchase, however, "Authentication is required...." dialog pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not "possible" but there is a trick.

You can use a release APK but Google needs to know the version of APK uploaded that enables IAB. For example, let's say your APK version code is 2. If Google can't find an APK code in Google Play with version code 2, then you can't test it. But, if you leave the APK code the same after uploading it to Google Play Alpha or Beta this can work.

You only need to upload an APK to ALPHA or BETA with the version code and IAB code with SKU configured, and use it in you device with code updates without changing the version code and version APK in gradle and use a release apk.

Add an account to test in your developer console for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the app in published status on alpha or beta. Any reason why you want to keep it in draft and not publish it? You can manage who can access the alpha apk through manage testers using googlegroup.